# Dart - Exception in IE10 on getBoundingClientRec()

Tags: javascript, dart

Here is a simple DART code that works perfectly in Chrome and FF but throws an exception in IE10:

```
import 'dart:html';

RangeInputElement inputPageSlider;

void main() {
  inputPageSlider = new RangeInputElement();
  inputPageSlider..id="pageslider" 
      ..className="leftFill ddrintslider"
      ..style.display="inline-block"
      ..style.whiteSpace="normal"
      ..style.marginTop="14px" 
      ..style.width="82%"
      ..style.height="1px"
      ..style.marginLeft="auto"
      ..style.marginRight="auto"
      ..value = '1'
      ..name="pageslider" ;


  print(inputPageSlider.getBoundingClientRect().width);
  print(inputPageSlider.getBoundingClientRect().left);

}
```

Here is the exception:

```
SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. 
ietest.dart.js, line 971 character 1
```

and code:

```
966: J.Fm(z.style,"auto")
967: J.GL(z.style,"auto")
968: y=J.RE(z)
969: y.sP(z,"1")
970: y.soc(z,"pageslider")
971: P.JS(J.DO($.i9.getBoundingClientRect()))
972: P.JS(J.hs($.i9.getBoundingClientRect()))}},1],])
973: I.$finishClasses($$,$,null)
```

The same problem happens with accessing `inputSlider.contentEdge` or `inputSlider.borderEdge`.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: dartbug.com has no similar bug listed.

Comment: I submitted it as an issue #19065.

Comment: Is it possible that you did not append the element to the DOM and IE simply doesn't know the client rect?

Try `print(inputPageSlider.getClientRects());` this gives me an empty list. But when I add the element to the DOM before, I get a rect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code implies that you don't add the element to the DOM. I guess IE is more strict here because an element that is not in the DOM doesn't have a client rect.

When I add the element to the body I will get a rectangle.

You can use `getClientRects()` instead. This will return an empty list instead of throwing an Exception.

Regards
Robert

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the case. My actual code is a bit more complex; I am passing the reference of the slider to another DART class that makes sizing decisions based on the slider dimensions; and, of course, I did it before adding the slider to its containing DOM...